# How get dimension of HTML shadow element via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, shadow-dom

I'm displaying tooltips via pure CSS3 but the only problem I have is that the content of the tooltips has really different lengths. Some of them are just 1 line long, others up to 4 lines.

Now are these tooltips [Shadow DOM](https://www.google.com/search?q=Shadow%20DOM) elements, so how could I get the (different) height of these tooltips via JavaScript (or a pure CSS solution would be better (maybe CSS calc?)) to adjust the margin that all tooltips have the margin from the anchor element?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-title="This is one example tooltip">Test #1</a>
<a href="#" data-title="This is one example tooltip - This is one example tooltip [...]">Test #2</a>
```

CSS:

```
a:before {
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    width: 440px;
    max-height: 72px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out 0.25s, margin-top 0.15s ease-out 0.25s;
}

a:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -40px;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out 0.5s, margin-top 0.2s ease-out 0.5s;
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qq3YJ/

Comment: Hi, while I don't have a direct answer, wouldn't it be better to put the tooltip after? Havalookat http://jsfiddle.net/anaran/FAkKG/1/

Comment: No, because the anchors have different lengths so the tooltip would be positioned different, additional the position of the tooltip should be always above the anchor.

Comment: So the anchors would be spaced unevenly vertically to accomodate the vertical space required by their tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the jsfiddle solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kwJz9/2/

This is what I did:

1. Make `a` relative, so this means that `a:before` element will have position relative to his parent `a`.
2. To place tooltip right under links I used `bottom` attribute instead of `margin-top`. Because I used `position: relative` to link - this means that `bottom:0` for example it is when tooltip has it's bottom border right on the bottom border of the parent `a`.
3. Because you want to see tooltips under links - in `:hover` I changed `bottom` to `1.4em`, which is little bit under text (`.4em` will be distance between them).
4. Because you want to see it animated I changed `transition` to include `bottom` property instead of 'margin-top'.
5. The last problem was that because you had `:before` element always in html flow - in case of second tooltip (which is big) - it occupies more space than `a`, so when you hover it (not the link) - you can see it. So I also added `visibility: hidden` to `:before` element to make sure that if mouse will be over it you will not see it.